# Django Foreign Key relationship and trying to filter to it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

Devices Model:

```
class Devices(AbstractFCMDevice):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

JobTags Model:

```
class JobTags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)  # Name of the tag
    job_base_rate = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Amount we take to escrow before a job begins
    job_unit_rate = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Rate per unit
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Name of the unit
    providers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

User Model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()
```

The line of code that's actually causing the error:

```
device = Devices.objects.filter(user__jobtags__name__contains=name)
```

Actual error I'm getting...

```
AttributeError: 'Devices' object has no attribute 'providers'
```

I feel like... of course Devices doesn't have a field called providers... but what am I doing wrong with my filter?

For some reason the code doesn't stop it actually runs through and does what I need it to, but it still gives me a 500 error... it's really weird.

is my filter query incorrect? Obviously, but is there a better way?

Comment: That error does not come from this code. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Please do add Full Traceback

Comment: So, apparently, I'm an idiot and spent the better part of that day with a localhost that I never restarted. So, the error was coming from code that never reset. Thank you for both of you for requesting to look into it further and I appreciate the code review and letting me know there's nothing wrong with the code you guys have in front of you <3